# How to fetch Powerpoint Slide from another .ppt File?

Tags: office365, powerpoint, powerpoint-2016

I have 10 powerpoints containing information about System A.

Now i want to create new Powerpoint which fetches data at run time from those 10 powerpoint files mention about SYstem A.

Also suppose if i do changes in any of 10 powerpoints, those shall reflect in new powerpoints.

Anyone have idea how to do so? I tried reuse slide but not successful as it comes one timer.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions about existing code projects. It's not a brain-storming or ideas site.

Comment: This would be a rather complex thing to tackle with VBA and would require that you create and install an add-in. Instead of inserting PPT slides, what about inserting images of the slides instead?  If you did that, you could link the images instead of inserting them; whenever the images change, PPT will update your presentation with the updated images whenever you open the "host" presentation.  No VBA required.